# Python - Tkinter - Checkbutton dinâmica não pega o valor da variável quando referenciada de outro arquivo/tela

Tags: python, tkinter

estou tendo o seguinte problema:
Consigo pegar o valor de uma variável dinâmica (checkbutton) quando todo o programa está em um só arquivo com apenas uma função:

```
import string
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
qtdvinhos = 3
linhacheck = 1
var=dict()
mostra = Tk()
mostra.geometry("650x400")
mostra.title("Sydvinn - Vinhos cadastrados")
def Lecheck(event):
    for x in range(1,qtdvinhos):
        stringcheck = 'Check ' + str(x) + ': ' +str(var[x].get())
        print(stringcheck)
for x in range(1,qtdvinhos):
    var[x]=IntVar()
    check1 = Checkbutton(mostra, variable=var[x])
    check1.grid(row=linhacheck, column=0)
    linhacheck= linhacheck+1
button_excluir = Button(mostra, text="Pega Valor")
button_excluir.bind("<Button-1>", Lecheck)
button_excluir.grid(row=4, column=4)

mostra.mainloop()
```

No entanto se separar o código em dois arquivos, cada um em uma tela e dois módulos, só consigo obter os valores 0 dos checkboxes:

Arquivo 1: DuasJanelasPT2

```
import string
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


class ChamaClasse:
    global Lecheck
    global var
    var={}
    global qtdvinhos
    qtdvinhos = 3

    def Lecheck(event):
        for x in range(1,qtdvinhos):
            stringcheck = 'Check ' + str(x) + ': ' +str(var[x].get())
            print(stringcheck)

    def Abrejanela(event):       
        global linhacheck
        linhacheck = 1
        mostra = Tk() 
        mostra.geometry("650x400")
        mostra.title("Sydvinn - Vinhos cadastrados")

        for x in range(1,qtdvinhos):
            var[x]=IntVar()
            check1 = Checkbutton(mostra, variable=var[x])
            check1.grid(row=linhacheck, column=0)
            linhacheck= linhacheck+1

        button_excluir = Button(mostra, text="Pega Valor")
        button_excluir.bind("<Button-1>", Lecheck)
        button_excluir.grid(row=4, column=4)

        mostra.mainloop()
```

Arquivo 2: DuasJanelasPT2

```
import string
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from DuasJanelasPT1 import ChamaClasse

novo = Tk()
novo.geometry("650x400")
novo.title("Sydvinn - Vinhos cadastrados")
checks = dict()


button_excluir = Button(novo, text="Chama o Mechama")
checks = button_excluir.bind("<Button-1>", ChamaClasse.Abrejanela)
button_excluir.grid(row=4, column=4)

novo.mainloop()
```

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa?

Answer (score 1):

As variáveis do outro arquivo podem ser acessadas normalmente se você importar o outro arquivo - mas sem ser com a sintaxe `from outro_arquivo import x`, e usar o nome do arquivo como prefixo:

Por exmplo, você poderia colocar todas as variáveis num arquivo
de nome `sys_vinho_variaveis.py` e usar uma linha assim

```
import sys_vinho_variaveis as var
```

E aí dentro desse arquivo você pode acessar as variáveis com `var.qtdvinhos` e assim por diante.

Seu código está bem bagunçado, mas as vezes fazer é o único jeito de aprender - eu recomendo um terceiro arquivo, por que senão você pode
cair num problema de dependencia circular de importação, do jeito que está trabalhando.

Outra nota: a palavra chave "global" só faz sentido dentro de funções - e diz que aquelas variáveis, dentro da função, vão estar visíveis naquele módulo (arquivo) - (e dessa forma vão estar visíveis dos outros arquivos usando a forma de prefixo, como mostrei acima): usar "global" dentro de classes e fora das funções não faz sentido. (Até faria diferença, mas a pessoa tem que saber *muito* Python para saber exatamente o que está fazendo, e mesmo assim, dificilmente seria a forma correta de fazer qualquer coisa).